# How to specify the header requesting JSON data using JSONRequest.get(...)?

Tags: javascript, json, http-headers

I'm following [this guide](http://www.json.org/JSONRequest.html) trying to set up JSON based communication. However, in order to take control, I'd like to specify the header contents. According to the information at the bottom, only *Content-Type* and *Content-Encoding* are specifiable. Is that correct understood?

If I've misunderstood, how can I specify the header in the call below?

```
var requestNumber = JSONRequest.get(
  "https://json.penzance.org/request",
  function(requestNumber, value, exception){
    if(value) {
      processResponse(value);
    } else {
      processError(exception);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood that documentation; those headers are certainly specifiable, but by the *server*. Which makes sense - they apply to the content you're requesting be sent back, with your GET. Also, I don't see any way to affect headers either way with JSONRequest, except for the gzip option.

Comment: "*JSONRequest is proposed as a new browser service ...*" - is this actually implemented anywhere?

Comment: @Kiyura When using *XMLHttpRequest*, I can specify the headers by *setRequestHeader* on the *XMLHttpRequest* object. I was expecting something like that in *JSONRequest* object too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark here. If you're successful creating *XMLHttpRequest* calls, why don't you use such for receiving JSON formatted data as well? Just because it's called *XML*, it doesn't have to be XML formatted data that is being sent.

Can you, for instance, make a call as you've used to with:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  ...
  var parsed = (new Function("return " + xhr.responseText))();
}
...
var someValue = parsed.someValue;
```

Of course, the exact *someValue* is defined by the contents of the JSON formatted data object. Also, **and this is an important note**, use the method above (the parser, if you will), only if you know that your data comes from a secure, reliable location. Otherwise, you may write your own, custom parser or download an existing one.

Comment: Why can't I use *JSONRequest*? It seems more logical.

Comment: You probably can (technically speaking) and maybe even should (ideologically speaking). But your post seems to show that you can not (practically speaking) and I gave you a suggestion of a work-around that works (pragmatically speaking). You asked your question over a week ago and my reply is the only one, as far I can see. You have the options of either accepting my advice or waiting a little bit longer (suggestably putting a bounty on it).